# mysql error unknown column 'abc'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM book_seat INNER JOIN seat ON book_seat.seat_id=seat.seat_id
                                INNER JOIN users ON book_seat.user_id=users.user_id
                                WHERE 1=1";
            if($type)
            {
               $sql.= " AND seat.type=$type";    
            }

            if($name)
            {
               $sql.= " AND users.name=$name";    
            }

            if($flightdate)
            {
                $sql.= " AND book_seat.date_booked=$flightdate";
            }

            if($seat)
            {
                $sql.=" AND seat.seat=$seat";
            }
```

Everything is ok with `$type`, `$flightdate` ,`$seat` but if i input `$name`, it gives error.e.g if i input abc, it gives the following. There is a column `name` in users table.

> Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'abc' in
>   'where clause' The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM book_seat
>   INNER JOIN seat ON book_seat.seat_id=seat.seat_id
>                                             INNER JOIN users ON book_seat.user_id=users.user_id
>                                             WHERE 1=1 AND users.name=abc'

Comment: Put the name variable in single quotes as it is a string

Comment: use backtick like `..AND \`users\`.\`name\`='$name'`

Comment: in users table have you a column with `name`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AND `users`.`name`='$name'
```